# how to save values in different sharedpreferences files and how to get values from each file separately?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save user email and user name in sharedpreferences file(filename ex:email&name), and save user movies in another sharedpreferences file(filename ex:usermovies), and finally get values from each file separately in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create `shared preference`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Here **MY_PREFS_NAME** indicate main shared preference storage identification.

Now you can save user email or user name or anything in shared preference and for that you need unique key. Imagine you want to save single user information in your application then you have to create different `key` for different `values`.

```
editor.putString("name", "username");
editor.putString("email", useremail);
editor.apply();
```

And for retrieving user information you have to use like that:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
String email= prefs.getString("email",  "No name defined");
```